# Создать правильно запрос на SQL с несколькими таблицами

Tags: sql, join, union

Есть 3 таблицы:

1. table_project - id_project, id_user, id_type, name_project, active_project
2. table_user - id_user, active_user
3. table_projectmeta - id, id_project, meta_key, meta_value

Запрос делаю следующего вида:

```sql
SELECT count(tbl_project.id_project) as count_project 
FROM table_project AS tbl_project 
JOIN table_user AS tbl_user ON tbl_user.id_user=tbl_project.id_user 
WHERE tbl_project.id_type IN ('1','3','61','59','55','6','4','51','25','26','50','63','54','30','20','8','52','83','7','24','5','64','57','56','29','19','9','27','2','31','22','53','60','21') 
  AND tbl_project.id_project IN (SELECT id_project 
                                 FROM (SELECT id_project 
                                       FROM table_projectmeta 
                                       WHERE (meta_key='Этажность' AND meta_value='1') 
                                          OR (meta_key='floors_count' AND meta_value='1') 
                                       UNION ALL 
                                       SELECT id_project 
                                       FROM table_projectmeta 
                                       WHERE meta_key='size_x' 
                                         AND meta_value BETWEEN '7' AND '7.99' 

                                       UNION ALL 
                                       SELECT id_project 
                                       FROM table_projectmeta 
                                       WHERE meta_key='size_y' 
                                         AND meta_value BETWEEN '10' AND '10.99') AS usr_prm 
                                  GROUP BY id_project 
                                  HAVING COUNT(id_project)>=3) 
  AND tbl_project.active_project='1' 
  AND tbl_user.active_user='1'
```

Запрос работает более 15 секунд.
Помогите, пожалуйста, оптимизировать запрос и ускорить получение результата.

Comment: вы бы этот `IN` подзапрос в группировкой убрали бы в `join`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вместо `IN` использовать `JOIN`?
Время обработки чуть более 12 секунд.

```sql
SELECT count(tbl_project.id_project) as count_project 
FROM table_project AS tbl_project 
JOIN table_user AS tbl_user ON tbl_user.id_user=tbl_project.id_user
JOIN table_projectmeta AS tbl_projectmeta ON tbl_projectmeta.id_project=tbl_project.id_project
JOIN table_projectmeta AS tbl_projectmeta1 ON tbl_projectmeta1.id_project=tbl_project.id_project
JOIN table_projectmeta AS tbl_projectmeta2 ON tbl_projectmeta2.id_project=tbl_project.id_project
WHERE tbl_project.id_type IN ('1','3','61','59','55','6','4','51','25','26','50','63','54','30','20','8','52','83','7','24','5','64','57','56','29','19','9','27','2','31','22','53','60','21') AND ((tbl_projectmeta.meta_key='Этажность' AND tbl_projectmeta.meta_value='1') OR (tbl_projectmeta.meta_key='floors_count' AND tbl_projectmeta.meta_value='1')) AND tbl_projectmeta1.meta_key='size_x' AND tbl_projectmeta1.meta_value BETWEEN '7' AND '7.99' AND tbl_projectmeta2.meta_key='size_y' AND tbl_projectmeta2.meta_value BETWEEN '10' AND '10.99' AND tbl_project.active_project='1' AND tbl_user.active_user='1'
```